# Vaadin 14 - How do I implement a grid with a checkbox column allowing operations on multiple rows?

Tags: java, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin 14 Flow application that presents a grid of tasks that can be added to and deleted from as well as editing a selected task. Currently I have it set up so that if the user clicks a row (single select), it opens an editor so they can edit the task.

What I'd like to do is have a checkbox on each row that can be used as a multi-row selector to allow deleting multiple rows.

Would it be easier to just have the table be multiple selection enabled and just delete whatever row(s) are selected? I assume multi-selection allows the usual shift-click to select a contiguous range and control-click to select rows at random.

If I switch to multi-select, how will this affect the ability to simply click a row and have it open an editor for that row? If multiple rows are selected, what is likely to happen?

---

Update:

I'd never used multi-select until now. I didn't realize it provides checkboxes out of the box (no pun intended).

Comment: "I'd never used multi-select until now. I didn't realize it provides checkboxes out of the box (no pun intended).", could you formulate that as an answer to this question, so that it is not left hanging around un-resolved. You can answer your own questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never used multi-select before and didn't realize that using that technique automatically adds a checkbox at the front of the row. Problem solved.